# How to call a Django view function Asynchronously (AJAX) using Vue

Tags: ajax, django, vue.js, vuejs2, django-views

I have a form with a button other then submit button. I would like Vue to call a Django view asynchronously when that button is clicked and return a JSON message saying function was called successfully.

Comment: OK. So what is your question? Did you try googling "vue ajax"?

Answer (score 2):

Jquery and Vue dont work well together. Vue works inside Jquery but Jquery doesnt work inside Vue. Better option is to use Axios for Ajax.
Call axios inside Vue method.

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken' //need this for method:post
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken' //need this for method:post

var vue_app = new Vue({
  el: '#id_xyz',
  data: {
    vue_var1:'hello',
    vue_var2:[],

  },
  methods:{
    ajax_method_name1:function(){
      console.log('Vue ajax_method_name1 is called');

      axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'ajax/url1/',//your customer url that is set in backend to do Ajax work
            data: {
                  axios_var1: this.vue_var1, //data to send to server

                },
            responseType: 'json', //server will response with this datatype
          })

          .then ( function (response){ //success function
              console.log('axios ajax success. data returned ==' + response.data); //if returned data format is like {[ {'id':1,'id':2} ]} we may have to do response.data['output_dict'][0]['id']
              this.vue_var2 = response.data['output_var'];
          }.bind(this)) //bind(this) is required when accessing Vue variable inside Axios success function (.then)

          .catch ( function (error){ //error function
            console.log('Axios ajax error');
          });

    },
  },

  delimiters: ["[[","]]"],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 different ways of doing Ajax with Vue as described in this [ARTICLE](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/08/28/vue-js-ajax-recipes/).

I dont fully understand it. Following is how you would do it using Jquery.

Javascript code :

```
$("#id1").blur(function() { //when field with id="id1" loses focus, Ajax happens
  var email_entered = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax/signup_email_verification/',
          type: "POST", //needs csrf token
          data: { email: email_entered,csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(), },
          dataType: 'json',

          success: function (data) {
              alert("Ajax successful");
          },
          error: function(error){
            alert("Ajax error");
          },
        });
});
```

Django code:

```
def email_verification(request):
    email=request.POST.get('email'); print('AJAX EMAIL = ',email)
    data={ 'success':True }
    return JsonResponse (data)
```

[HERE](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa) are few preferred ways to do Ajax with plain JS or Jquery or Fetch or Axios.